# Can you use a background image in CSS with trigger.io?

Tags: trigger.io

Im trying to use a background image in a trigger.io ios mobile app but they dont seem to work.  When I use catalyst it lists the image location in some temporary local file that doesn't exist.

Is it possible to use the background-image property in CSS with trigger.io and if so, how do I get it to work?

Comment: Good question.  I have always just used jQuery/zepto to set my images utilizing the forge.tools.getURL('img/play18x18.png', function(path) {]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a DOM element on the fly with zepto or jQuery:

```
forge.tools.getURL('img/yourImage.png', function(path) { 
   var el = $('<div style="background-image: url(' + path + ')"></div>');
});
```

Or if you just need to set it via zepto or jQuery:

```
forge.tools.getURL('img/yourImage.png', function(path) { 
   $("#yourElement").css("background-image", "url(" + path + ")");
});
```

Note: I've been using **backbone.js** and I just pass the "path" variable to my view that does not know anything about *forge.tools.getURL*.

Comment: wow - never knew about that.  Ill definitely give that a try.  thanks

Comment: well the method worked but the application did not :(  Thanks for the tip.